# SQL Query: I want to display UserName and role_discription using a junction table

Tags: sql, sql-server

Hi can someone please help?

I have three tables `tblUsers`, `tblRoles` and `tblUserRoles`

How do I display `UserName` from a `tblUsers` table and `role_discription` 
from `tblRoles` table.

```
    CREATE TABLE tblRoles(
    roleID int IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    role_description varchar(50) NOT NULL
    );

    )CREATE TABLE tblUsers(
    userID int IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    FirstName varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    LastName varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    Age int NOT NULL,
    UserName varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    Password varchar(50) NOT NULL);


    create table tblUserRoles (
    userID int REFERENCES tblUsers(userID) NOT NULL,
    roleID int REFERENCES tblRoles(roleID)NOT NULL,
    );

    alter table tblUserRoles
    Add Constraint PK_UserRoles
    Primary Key Clustered (userID,roleID)
```

I know basic SELECT statements and can show everything in tblUserRoles table but would like to show names and descriptions instead of ID numbers

Comment: hint : `JOIN` ....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a query to display user_name and role_description

```
  SELECT t1.UserName  , t2.role_description  from tblUsers t1 INNER JOIN tblUserRoles t3 ON t1.userID = t3.userID INNER JOIN tblRoles t2 on t3.roleID  = t2.roleID
```

Here the 1st join will join tables tblUsers and tblUserRoles on column userID and the 2nd join will join tables tblUserRoles and tblRoles on column roleID.